# auth_token Node.js > Instagram

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, instagram-api

Pra fazer um script funcionar eu preciso do `auth_token` de um aplicativo do instagram, e que segundo instruções eu devo(e estou) fazendo assim:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=1627c123e3fc481791e0d6be16ff57a0&redirect_uri=http://yourcallback.com/auth/instagram/callback&response_type=token&display=touch&scope=likes+relationships
```

Mas ainda recebo os erros:

> Instagram {
>       "code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message":
>    "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"
>   }

Alguém sabe indicar o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Pelos testes que eu já fiz com a API , você precisa ter uma url para colocar em **redirect_uri**. A url que você está usando não deve ser aceita pela API.

Quando vc registrou seu aplicativo deve ter inserido uma url , deve ser usada essa mesma URL.

O erro que a API devolveu para você diz exatamente isso.